# Proper way to get the windows UserName

Tags: c#, .net, environment-variables

I need to access the username of the currently logged in Windows user. I have been using `Environment.UserName` in [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) thinking it would do the trick. But it's not giving me exactly what I want.

I have a user who setup his computer with a certain username. Let's call it "UserName 1". He then went into the control panel and changed the account name to "UserName New".

I want to capture "UserName New". But when I call `Environment.UserName`, it gives me "UserName 1". "UserName 1" is still the user's folder path on the hard drive. But his user name shows up as "UserName New" all throughout the rest of Windows. How do I capture that actual username that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```